# JQuery split comma delimited from ashx handler

Tags: jquery, ashx

I am having trouble splitting  a comma delimited string into an array. In my ashx handler page, my string looks like this:

```
context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9} ", BusProfileID, BusinessName, BusinessPhone, BusinessEmail, BusinessAddress, BusinessCity, BusinessState, BusinessZip, BusinessWebsite, BusinessCategory));
```

When I try to do an array the results are not shown.

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_businessSelect').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    contentType: "text/html; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "ID=" + $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_businessSelect').val(),
                    url: "getBusValue.ashx",
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function (data) {
                    var vardata = JSON.stringify(data)
                    var arr = vardata.split(',')
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusProfileID").val(arr[0]);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessName").val(arr[1];
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessPhone").val(arr[2]);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessEmail").val(arr[3]);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessAddress").val(arr[4]);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessCity").val(arr[5]);
                  $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessState").val(arr[6]).prop('selected',true);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessZip").val(arr[7]);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessWebsite").val(arr[8]);
                   $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BusinessCategory").val(arr[9]).prop('selected', true);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is my ashx page:

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        string ID = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT BusProfileID, BusinessName, BusinessPhone, BusinessEmail, BusinessAddress, BusinessCity, BusinessState, BusinessZip, BusinessWebsite, BusinessCategory FROM [BusProfile] WHERE BusinessName = @BusinessName", conn);
        comm.Parameters.Add("@BusinessName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar);
        comm.Parameters["@BusinessName"].Value = ID;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                string BusProfileID = reader["BusProfileID"].ToString();
                string BusinessName = reader["BusinessName"].ToString();
                string BusinessPhone = reader["BusinessPhone"].ToString();
                string BusinessEmail = reader["BusinessEmail"].ToString();
                string BusinessAddress = reader["BusinessAddress"].ToString();
                string BusinessCity = reader["BusinessCity"].ToString();
                string BusinessState = reader["BusinessState"].ToString();
                string BusinessZip = reader["BusinessZip"].ToString();
                string BusinessWebsite = reader["BusinessWebsite"].ToString();
                string BusinessCategory = reader["BusinessCategory"].ToString();

                context.Response.Write(string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9} ", BusProfileID, BusinessName, BusinessPhone, BusinessEmail, BusinessAddress, BusinessCity, BusinessState, BusinessZip, BusinessWebsite, BusinessCategory));
            }
            reader.Close();
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

This is how the data looks like in the textboxes upon success:

```
8,My Business Inc,(702) 555-1212,123@aol.com,555 anywhere street,Los Angeles,California,44502,google.com,Hotel & Travel
```

Comment: Can you show the result of statement `var arr = data.split(',')`?

Comment: you are just writing the whole string into the element...

Comment: Comma seperate them as commented by @Satpal use data.split(',') to do that.

Comment: @Satpal I tried your suggestion and it did not work

Comment: what error shows up?

Comment: Have you used `arr[0], arr[1]`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using JSON ? JSON seems like it would speed this up quite a bit.

Comment: No data shows in the textboxes. This how how the string looks like:8,My Business Inc,(702) 555-1212,123@aol.com,555 anywhere streeet,Los Angeles,California,44502,http://www.google.com,Hotel & Travel

Comment: @Satpal yes I did. I updated my example. No data shows in the textbox.

Comment: @Jhecht Should I be using JSON? I didn't think there was a reason too. I am pulling data from a database as part of a page that the user can edit their information

Comment: A lot of things that communicate with Javascript tend to use JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) because Javascript can go back and forth between the data pretty easily. I don't know much about asp.NET, but I'm 99.999% sure it either has native support for JSON or a library.

Comment: what is the object you receive as `data` in the ajax? would you paste that result? all the rest of your code seems to be fine

Comment: I use JSON all the time with asmx pages, you should not have any issues with the built in library. However, I prefer Newtonsoft, with is free, for the back end. It handles dates better

Comment: I will post a sample shortly

Comment: @PrashanthBenny I updated the question to show how the output data looks upon success

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demonstration of the code.

```
var string = "8,my business inc,(702) 555-1212,123@aol.com,555 anywhere street,Los Angeles,california,44502,google.com,hotel and ttravel";

var stringArray = string.split(',');

console.log(stringArray);
```

**The result is here:**

**["8", "my business inc", "(702) 555-1212", "123@aol.com", "555 anywhere street", "Los Angeles", "california", "44502", "google.com", "hotel and ttravel"]**

```
console.log(xm[5]);
```

output: 
**Los Angeles**

if the data that you get on success is a string, then possibly here is how the flow goes.....

I don't think there is any error in the code that you've written.

if data is not a string, then

do `var string = "" + data;` to convert it to a string.

Comment: I added  var vardata = JSON.stringify(data) to the code and it works now.

Comment: In this case, JSON.Stringify(data) just converts data into string datatype.

Comment: it is almost as same as `data = "" + data;` in this  case... Have a reference to this link [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

this is a lenthy post but I hope it helps you.

First part is the web service that is used two different ways, one way as a web service, the other as a regular  class that makes a list and serializes it.

webservice1.asmx:

```
    namespace WebApplication1
    {    // a class in context with how the data are is being used
        [Serializable]
        public class select2
        {
            public String id { get; set; }
            public String text { get; set; }
            public select2(String code, String name)
            {
                this.id = code;
                this.text = name;
            }
        }
        // input parms not used but to show concept
        public struct parameters
        {
            string parm1;
            string parm2;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Summary description for WebService1
        /// </summary>
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {

            [WebMethod]
            public string GetAList(String s)
            {
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                parameters parms = ser.Deserialize<parameters>(s);
                return makelist();
            }

             // return a list of serialized codes and countries
            public String makelist()
            {
                List<select2> list = new List<select2>();

                list.Add(new select2("AI", "Anguilla"));
                list.Add(new select2("AQ", "Antarctica"));
                list.Add(new select2("AG", "Antigua and Barbuda"));
                list.Add(new select2("AR", "Argentina"));
                list.Add(new select2("AM", "Armenia"));
                list.Add(new select2("AW", "Aruba"));
                list.Add(new select2("AU", "Australia"));
                list.Add(new select2("AT", "Austria"));
                list.Add(new select2("AZ", "Azerbaijan"));
                list.Add(new select2("BS", "Bahamas"));
                list.Add(new select2("BH", "Bahrain"));
                list.Add(new select2("BD", "Bangladesh"));
                list.Add(new select2("BB", "Barbados"));
                list.Add(new select2("BY", "Belarus"));
                list.Add(new select2("BE", "Belgium"));
                list.Add(new select2("BZ", "Belize"));
                // did it this way to show you which to use
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                String jsonList = ser.Serialize(list);
                return jsonList;
            }
        }
    }
```

The next section is the code behind section:

```
    namespace WebApplication1
    {

        public partial class select2 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            public String JsonCountries { get
            {
                    // use the web service as a regular class to return the serialized list
                return (new WebService1()).makelist();
            } }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

and finally the aspx page that populates one select2 box from an ajax call to the web method and the second select 2 that is populated from data put in place by the code behind.  It is a little different from what you were doing but the proof of concept was already in place and should give you enough to go by.

```
       $(document).ready(
                function () {
                    // property on code behnd
                    var cblist = <%=JsonCountries%>;
                    $("#sel3").select2({  data:cblist });

                    parms = JSON.stringify({ parm1: "one", parm2: "two" });

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "WebService1.asmx/GetAList",
                             data: JSON.stringify( {s:parms}),
                            type: 'post',
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",

                            success: function (data, status) {
                                var contries = JSON.parse(data.d);
                                $("#sel2").select2({ data: contries });
                            },
                            error: function (one, two) {
                                debugger;
                            }
                        });

                }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
        <body>
           <div>
               <p>populated from ajax</p>
               <select id="sel2"></select>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p>populated from code behind</p>
                <select id="sel3"></select>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```